# Drawing a radial tree from node and edges rather than children

Tags: d3.js, tree, neo4j

I was able to draw a graph with d3 from neo4j data, but I'm struggling in drawing a tree. Examples  I've seen use a json file in which each node contains an array of its own children. Although this looks pretty convenient, it's not easy - at least to me - to interface with neo4j. Indeed, neo4j wouldn't let one return {nodes: collect(distinct {name: n.name, children: collect(distinct {name: m.name})})} from a (n)--(m) graph. It would however let one return collections of nodes and edges from a path.

My question, would it be possible to draw a tree in d3 from nodes and edges without having children for each node in the data structure?

Many thanks in advance
Pierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypher query to retrieve nodes and relationships from neo4j would be:

```
MATCH p=() <-[:REPORTS8TO]- ()
UNWIND nodes(p) AS n UNWIND rels(p) AS r 
WITH n, r ORDER BY n.Name 
RETURN {nodes: COLLECT(DISTINCT n), links: COLLECT(DISTINCT {source: id(endNode(r)), target: id(startNode(r))})}
```

Hence, javascript and d3 code:
- extract nodes and relationships from json

```
var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
var json = obj.data[0][0];

var nodeMap = {};
json.nodes.forEach(function(x) {
    nodeMap[x.id] = x;
    nodeMap[x.id].children = [];
});

var links = json.links.map(function(x) {
    nodeMap[x.source].children.push(nodeMap[x.target]);
    return { source: nodeMap[x.source], target: nodeMap[x.target] };
});
```

draw the tree

```
d3.select("#tree").select("svg").remove();

var width = 280, height = 870;

var margin = {
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 10,
        right: 120
    }

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, width - margin.left - margin.right]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var vis = d3.select("#tree").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom )
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Compute the new tree layout from root
var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(), links = tree.links(nodes);

var link = vis.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", diagonal);

var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + ", " + d.x + ")"; })

node.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 9)
    .attr("height", 9)
    .attr("y", -4)
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "node "+d.type; } );

node.append("text")
    .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.children ? -14 : 14; })
    .attr("dy", 4)
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "end" : "start"; })
    .attr("class", function(d) {return "node "+d.type+" text"; })
    .attr("style", "stroke-wdth: 0.5px; font: 10px sans-serif;")
    .text(function(d) { if (d.Name != "Panel") { return d.Name; }});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this for a cypher query that returns the manager(s) and their respective children.

```
match (manager)<-[:REPORTS_TO]-(direct_reports)
return id(manager), collect(id(direct_reports))
```

Comment: Indeed, this works and is similar to the cypher query I was describing. According yo the d3 tree.js example, I need to have both the list of nodes and their children, and the list of edges. With your query I can report the list of nodes and their children, but if I do the same with edges, in the same query to avoid traversing the graph twice, it fails: match (:Panel {Name: "Panel"}) <-[:belongsTo]- (n:Panel) <-[:belongsTo]- (c:Cell) return {name: n.Name, children: collect(distinct {name: c.Name})}, {edges: collect(distinct {src: n.Name, tgt: c.Name})}

Comment: When you say `edge` I think you mean the relationships `belongsTo` but you actually mean the children's children or grand children.  Is that a fair statement?

Comment: The graph starts with a tree with a panel of tumors and cell lines associated to those. I named the relationships belongsTo. Each tumor is connected to a root node named panel. What I try to do is to display that tree with d3 radial-tree, so my query starts from the root node and returns for each node its children and all relationships tagged edges in the json format.

Comment: The D3 example read a json file containing nested nodes ultimately attached to root, as I can't - don't know how to - produce that file from a single cypher query, I tried reporting a single level of nodes and their children as well as the relationships (links) to build the tree directly from nodes and links. There must be an easier way, but I didn't find any example that would start from a json file.